# tk windows in Jupyter

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, jupyter

I'm trying to get a tk window to display inline in Jupyter -- similar to the effect that `%matplotlib inline` has, but for a non-matplotlib tk window.  Specifically, I'm trying to get [graphics.py](http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/) windows to display inline.  Here would be a minimal working example:

```
# Some kind of replacement for %matplotlib inline:
%gui tk    # <--- doesn't solve the problem, only connects the event loops?

# minimal graphics.py working example:
from graphics import *
c = Circle(Point(50,50), 10)
c.draw(win)
win.getMouse() # Pause to view result
win.close()    # Close window when done
```

Is this possible/feasible?  If it's not already implemented, is this something I could attempt to make myself?